# Block requests via intermediate host names at nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a setup where users are supposed to send requests to A.com. Requests are sent to a CDN which further sends request to A-reader.com, and A-reader routes the request to nginx.

I want A-reader to be accessible only via CDN, so, the aim is to block any request where original request url is not A.com. If any user types `A-reader.com/<anything>` in browser address bar, requests should be blocked at nginx

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - You can use the nginx http referrer module - http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html

In your case, since you only want to allow A.com, the configuration should be something like:

```
valid_referers *.A.com;
if ($invalid_referer) {
    return 403;
}
```

You'll have to customize the valid referral list to match your domain.

---

Alternatively, you can do regex matching on $http_referer:

```
 if ($http_referer ~* (babes|click|diamond|forsale|girl|jewelry|love|nudit|poker|porn))
    {  return 403;   }
```

(HTTP referer from https://calomel.org/nginx.html via [How to block referral spam using Nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457447/how-to-block-referral-spam-using-nginx))

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using a similar approach. I used $host header instead, and it worked for me